# Can't execute embedded Glassfish App at Apple platform

Tags: macos, glassfish, java-ee-5, java-6, glassfish-embedded

I'm having a problem running an JEE5 application at GF 3.1 Embedded at Apple computers... (the same environment works at Linux and Windows). The server starts ok, but when loading the APP the server returns a SEVERE message... My deployment is basically the glassfish-embedded-web-3.1.jar file, the configured domain with app inside, and a start class.

The output can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/ypeV3jm3; and the lines 44 and 48 show the error messages. At linux/windows platform (where it works) the lines there goes for JSF, Mojarra and RichFaces start (look at them here: http://pastebin.com/y4TaA5vY)!

I thank you for some help here.

Comment: A long time ago, but this might have to do with the case-insensitivity (by default) of OS X’s file system (unfortunately, there’s no stack trace in the log). See [Fixed: Embedded Jetty Fails To Unpack With FileNotFoundException: Not a directory](https://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2013/10/04/fixed-embedded-jetty-fails-to-unpack-with-filenotfoundexception-not-a-directory/).